What aircraft can an NPPL SSEA holder fly?
I want to add an SSEA rating to my NPPL license (currently with a Microlight rating) so that I can fly 4 seats.
Wikipedia for the NPPL says:

NPPL holders may not:

fly non-UK registered aircraft
fly "EASA aircraft"


But the NPPL website says

Can I fly my 'N' registered aircraft on my NPPL?
Yes, because the FAA have confirmed that 14 CFR 61.3 permits the holder of a UK-issued sub-ICAO licence, such as the NPPL or LAPL, to operate a US (N) registered aircraft within the UK.

So these two sources seem to contradict each other, can you fly a US aircraft, such as a Cessna 150 on this license or not?
The main reason I want this rating is to fly 4 seat aircraft, so which ones exactly can you fly with this rating?

A Cessna 150 might have been manufactured in the US (or Reims in France) but that doesnt make it a "US" or "French" aircraft for the purpose of licensing. What matters is the state or territory where it is registered.
An NPPL generally lets you fly G-registered aircraft (ie, those on the UK CAA register). What you seem to have found is that there is also a dispensation to be able to fly FAA (ie, N-registered) aircraft too.
As it says on the CAA website emphasis mine

Following an amendment to the UK Aircrew Regulations in 2021, the holder of a licence issued in accordance with the Air Navigation Order 2016 (as amended) (PPL(A) or NPPL(A)) with a valid SSEA or SLMG class rating(s) can now also fly a UK (G) registered Part 21 aeroplane or motor glider.

The two most common four seaters you'll find are part 21 - Cessna 172 & PA28

Thanks Jamie, this helps clear things up. A 172 seems such a big leap from a C42, that it's a bit nuts to me you can technically convert in a few hours...

They're really not as different as you possibly think. Both fairly simple types.

Hey Jamie, so this has only been the case since 2021? Which I assume means it could change again in the other direction in the future
